# Make a link open on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make hyper link `<a>Link</a>` a double click link: i:e link should open on double click and single click should do nothing.

Comment: You can do that with JavaScript: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html But if it is not for a very special case I would not advice to do so. Users are not used to double click on a link. Always follow the principle of the least surprise.

Comment: Is there a problem with the regular single click?

Comment: Just curious, what's the use-case?  Behaving *unlike* the other 99.99% of the web generally isn't a good idea.

Comment: I am calling a zend frame work action like this.<a href=/module/actionNae></a> . I just want to call it when user double clicks on link.

Comment: Usecase: I am doing inline editing on table. When I click any <td> data it should open a form in that <tr>. But client want to use double click to open form in that <tr>. <td> data does not look like link but when I db click it, it should call an action.

Comment: @Muhammad Zeeshan: Ok, that is a fair usecase.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay, so, you **can** do this:

HTML:

```
<a id='golink' href='gosomewhere.html'>Go Somewhere</a>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#golink').click(function() {
        return false;
    }).dblclick(function() {
        window.location = this.href;
        return false;
    });
});
```

Live copy:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#golink').click(function() {
        return false;
    }).dblclick(function() {
        window.location = this.href;
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<a id='golink' href='http://stackoverflow.com' target="_blank">Go Somewhere</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*(It doesn't have to be an ID; you can do this with a class or anything else that lets you form a selector that jQuery can process to hook things up.)*

If the user has JavaScript disabled, the link will work normally. Crawlers will find the link normally, etc. If a user has JavaScript enabled, the event handlers will get hooked up and it will require a double click.

The above blows away keyboard navigation, though, so then you have to handle that:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#golink').click(function() {
        return false;
    }).dblclick(function() {
        window.location = this.href;
        return false;
    }).keydown(function(event) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 13: // Enter
            case 32: // Space
                window.location = this.href;
                return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Live copy:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#golink').click(function() {
        return false;
    }).dblclick(function() {
        window.location = this.href;
        return false;
    }).keydown(function(event) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 13: // Enter
            case 32: // Space
                window.location = this.href;
                return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<a id='golink' href='http://stackoverflow.com' target="_blank">Go Somewhere</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I can't imagine this is good for accessibility, and I bet there are other things not catered for above. Which all feeds into:

But I'd **strongly recommend against doing it** without a ***really good*** use case.

Comment: +1: this is the only answer that will properly work without JS.

Comment: Well according to OP, without JS it won't work properly, since he want's his god damned double click :)

Comment: Usecase: I am doing inline editing on table. When I click any <td> data it should open a form in that <tr>. But client want to use double click to open form in that <tr>. <td> data does not look like link but when I db click it, it should call an action.

Comment: Didn't work without `.preventDefault()` on (single) click.

Comment: @IvanaG.B. - It does with jQuery, because `return false` in a jQuery event handler means both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. It doesn't in a native DOM handler because that isn't true in native DOM handlers.

Answer (score 6):

Try using span instead of a link. Something like this:

```
<span ondblclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" style="color:blue;text-decoration: underline;">Click Here</span>
```

Comment: Although that it is true and may be better ways, my answer does what he want. Didn't understand the negative.

Comment: @Guilherme Oenning: There are much better ways of implementing what the OP wants: although he shouldn't in the first place implement a double click, if he wants to do that he should do it with an `<a>` not a `<span>`.

Comment: But what he wants should not be called a `link`, it's more like a button, that's why I used the `<span>`.

Comment: @Guilherme: *"But what he wants should not be called a `link`, it's more like a button..."* Fair point! I wouldn't make it look like one, then, but it's still a fair point.

Comment: @Oenning: Then use `<button>`. :P

Answer (score 1):

Great question, I have been looking for an answer. I came up with this (tested in Chrome).  Add these attributes to your link:

```
onclick="return false" ondblclick="location=this.href"
```

e.g.

```
<a onclick="return false" ondblclick="location=this.href" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: Obviously, you need to take extra steps if you want to use the 'target' behaviour, but for simple stuff, mine works.

Answer (score -1):

You can do so using Javascript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascripot:void(0)" ondblclick="javascript:DoMyWorkFunction()">a:x</a>
```

Comment: You don't use `javascript:` in DOM0 (attribute) event handlers. Only `href` and the like.

Comment: Why cant we use javascript: ?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<a ondblclick= "openLink('your_link')">Link</a>

<script>
function openLink(link)
{
   location.href = link;
}
</script>
```

OR

```
<a ondblclick="location.href='your_link'">Double click on me</a>
```

Comment: `a` elements without `name` or `href` attributes are invalid: http://validator.w3.org