# How to trigger a link (a tag) with double click instead of single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way that I can keep all the hover effects but trigger the  tag link (to another page) only when double clicking?
Thanks!

Any pure javascript answer? (no jQuery)

Comment: Heard of ondblclick() ? Easy: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp

Comment: ahh!! thanks guys! I googled so much but i guess i had totally wrong keywords

Comment: @RiteshA Really? W3Schools?

Comment: weird ondbclick wont work in my case, the tab still jump out. i have to use scripts. return false on single click won't work either :( however, @Amine Hajyoussef 's answer works just fine for me using pure js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came with this (without jQuery, using only an onclick event handler):

```
  var clicked=false;
  var el = document.getElementById('link');
  var maxClicksDelay = 500; // in milliseconds 
  el.onclick = function(e) {
    if(!clicked) {
    clicked = true;
    setTimeout(function() { clicked = false}, maxClicksDelay );  
    e.preventDefault();
    }

  }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pindexis/5acSW/)

Comment: While this might work, it is not an optimal solution, because of the “magic number” `500` in the `setTimeout` here – the user can customize in their system, from which time span apart two clicks count as a double click, and this solution does not take that into account …

Comment: Maybe I'm pessimist, but why not use `ondblclick` ?

Comment: @NULL somehow ondbclick wont work for me...i tried many times :( I have to use script to do it

Comment: @user2206436 please check, that you correctly typed `ondblclick`.

Answer (score 4):

I would of course won't go against one click standard, but if that's what you wish:

You can find an answer to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562012/make-a-link-open-on-double-click)

Copying from the answer above:

HTML:

```
<a id='golink' href='gosomewhere.html'>Go Somewhere</a>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
     $('#golink').click(function() {
         return false;
     }).dblclick(function() {
         window.location = this.href;
         return false;
     }).keydown(function(event) {
         switch (event.which) {
             case 13: // Enter
             case 32: // Space
                 window.location = this.href;
                 return false;
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! this is helpful! Coz i wanna preserve single click to navigate the page. and the link isn't the main point of the site i am making.

Comment: Any javascript version of this? I was hoping not to use jQuery, but somehow I don't know how to combine those click, dbclick functions

Comment: You have @amine's answer below, for the non-jQuery version

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add an attribute to handle links with a double click option.

```
<a href='http://...' dblclick>Link</a>
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

At the end of your html document add this lines to find anchors with a specific 'dblclick' attribute:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
    $('a[dblclick]').click(function(e){
       return false; // disable single click
    }).dblclick(function(e){
       window.location = this.href; // on double click go to the URL from href value
    })
  })
</script>
```