# auto double click with only javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, web

I want to make an autoDoubleClick function by only javascript.Example:

```
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("double",function(e){
        alert("Some thing");
    });
```

when we call function

```
autoDoubleClick(btn)
```

so it will auto double click.
Can you give me some ideal ??? (only javascript no jquery)

Comment: here is an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479948/how-to-trigger-a-link-a-tag-with-double-click-instead-of-single-click

Comment: Are you trying to listen for a double click, or actually perform a double click?

Answer (score 1):

The event name is `dblclick`. For triggering the event you can use the `HTMLElement.prototype.dispatchEvent` method:

```
btn.dispatchEvent(new Event('dblclick'));
```

Comment: @Lucy What works on IE? :) That method is related to `addEventListener`. The method support on IE is similar to `addEventListener`. For supporting older versions of IE you can define helper functions. Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720431/javascript-dispatchevent-click-is-not-working-in-ie9-and-ie10